# TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-link

I am having below data frame and wanted to save the data frame as a CSV file in the Azure Data lake. My data frame is called 'df'. I am using Azure Synpase Notebook

[image]

```
df.to_csv('abfss://jobsdata@strxxxuei.dfs.core.windows.net/Jobs_newdata/data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Getting the below error message when I tried to run the above code,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6713/3472604753.py in <module>
----> 1 df.to_csv('abfss://jobsdata@strxxxuei.dfs.core.windows.net/Jobs_newdata/jobs.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3385         )
   3386 
-> 3387         return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
   3388             path_or_buf,
   3389             line_terminator=line_terminator,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1081             formatter=self.fmt,
   1082         )
-> 1083         csv_formatter.save()
   1084 
   1085         if created_buffer:

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    226         """
    227         # apply compression and byte/text conversion
--> 228         with get_handle(
    229             self.filepath_or_buffer,
    230             self.mode,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    556 
    557     # open URLs
--> 558     ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    559         path_or_buf,
    560         encoding=encoding,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    331 
    332         try:
--> 333             file_obj = fsspec.open(
    334                 filepath_or_buffer, mode=fsspec_mode, **(storage_options or {})
    335             ).open()

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in open(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, protocol, newline, **kwargs)
    427     ``OpenFile`` object.
    428     """
--> 429     return open_files(
    430         urlpath=[urlpath],
    431         mode=mode,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in open_files(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, name_function, num, protocol, newline, auto_mkdir, expand, **kwargs)
    279     be used as a single context
    280     """
--> 281     fs, fs_token, paths = get_fs_token_paths(
    282         urlpath,
    283         mode,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in get_fs_token_paths(urlpath, mode, num, name_function, storage_options, protocol, expand)
    597                         "share the same protocol"
    598                     )
--> 599             cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    600             optionss = list(map(cls._get_kwargs_from_urls, urlpath))
    601             paths = [cls._strip_protocol(u) for u in urlpath]

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py in get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    209         bit = known_implementations[protocol]
    210         try:
--> 211             register_implementation(protocol, _import_class(bit["class"]))
    212         except ImportError as e:
    213             raise ImportError(bit["err"]) from e

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py in _import_class(cls, minv)
    232     else:
    233         mod, name = cls.rsplit(".", 1)
--> 234         mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
    235         return getattr(mod, name)
    236 

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec_wrapper/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .core import (
      2     AzureBlobFileSystem
      3 )
      4 
      5 __all__ = [

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec_wrapper/core.py in <module>
      3 from .utils import logger as synapseml_pandas_logger
      4 from .utils.common import SynapseCredential
----> 5 import adlfs
      6 import time
      7 import re

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adlfs/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .spec import AzureDatalakeFileSystem
      2 from .spec import AzureBlobFileSystem, AzureBlobFile
      3 from ._version import get_versions
      4 
      5 __all__ = ["AzureBlobFileSystem", "AzureBlobFile", "AzureDatalakeFileSystem"]

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adlfs/spec.py in <module>
     16     ResourceExistsError,
     17 )
---> 18 from azure.storage.blob._shared.base_client import create_configuration
     19 from azure.datalake.store import AzureDLFileSystem, lib
     20 from azure.datalake.store.core import AzureDLFile, AzureDLPath

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/__init__.py in <module>
      8 from typing import Union, Iterable, AnyStr, IO, Any, Dict  # pylint: disable=unused-import
      9 from ._version import VERSION
---> 10 from ._blob_client import BlobClient
     11 from ._container_client import ContainerClient
     12 from ._blob_service_client import BlobServiceClient

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py in <module>
     24 
     25 from ._shared import encode_base64
---> 26 from ._shared.base_client import StorageAccountHostsMixin, parse_connection_str, parse_query, TransportWrapper
     27 from ._shared.encryption import generate_blob_encryption_data
     28 from ._shared.uploads import IterStreamer

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/base_client.py in <module>
     38 from .constants import STORAGE_OAUTH_SCOPE, SERVICE_HOST_BASE, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, READ_TIMEOUT
     39 from .models import LocationMode
---> 40 from .authentication import SharedKeyCredentialPolicy
     41 from .shared_access_signature import QueryStringConstants
     42 from .request_handlers import serialize_batch_body, _get_batch_request_delimiter

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/authentication.py in <module>
     20 
     21 try:
---> 22     from azure.core.pipeline.transport import AioHttpTransport
     23 except ImportError:
     24     AioHttpTransport = None

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
     66                 if name == 'AioHttpTransport':
     67                     try:
---> 68                         from ._aiohttp import AioHttpTransport
     69                         return AioHttpTransport
     70                     except ImportError:

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_aiohttp.py in <module>
     33 import asyncio
     34 import codecs
---> 35 import aiohttp
     36 from multidict import CIMultiDict
     37 

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 from . import hdrs as hdrs
----> 6 from .client import (
      7     BaseConnector as BaseConnector,
      8     ClientConnectionError as ClientConnectionError,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py in <module>
     33 from yarl import URL
     34 
---> 35 from . import hdrs, http, payload
     36 from .abc import AbstractCookieJar
     37 from .client_exceptions import (

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/http.py in <module>
      5 from . import __version__
      6 from .http_exceptions import HttpProcessingError as HttpProcessingError
----> 7 from .http_parser import (
      8     HeadersParser as HeadersParser,
      9     HttpParser as HttpParser,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py in <module>
     13 from . import hdrs
     14 from .base_protocol import BaseProtocol
---> 15 from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
     16 from .http_exceptions import (
     17     BadStatusLine,

~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py in <module>
    665 
    666 
--> 667 class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout):
    668     def __enter__(self) -> async_timeout.timeout:
    669         if self._timeout is not None:

TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I am getting the above error message, not sure how to rectify it.

Can anyone advise what is the issue in my code?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if `to_csv()` can use path like `abfss://...`. It rather works with local path

Comment: @furas sorry, I updated the full error message. Also, I followed the Microsoft documentation regarding saving as a CSV file.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool) . I am using an azure synapse notebook.

Comment: It looks like `to_csv()` eventually manages to figure out that the file being saved is being saved to an Azure Blob, but then some default parameter gets assigned the wrong value. Is the Azure Blob you're writing to configured to allow public writing without authentication? Because it seems likely that's not the case, in which case you'd need to look at how to reuse a previously opened connection, or what to pass in `storage_options` for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to invalid permission to access the container or you may not have write permissions to the container.

I have repro’d with your code and was able to write the data to CSV successfully.

```
df.to_csv('abfss://<container name>@<storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/source/sample2.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to give or check the permission to the container? I checked all the permissions are available